# Measurement of dipole electric field generated by a polar molecule

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrochemistry

I'm trying to understand the nature of polar molecules. Have there been experiments where we can say to have actually measured the dipole electric field generated by a polar molecule such as hydrogen fluoride HF?
The idealized experiment I have in mind for example is tracking the deflection angle of a free test particle (electron) as it passes near a single HF molecule...

Comment: see e.g., Miller, Bederson: Electric Dipole Polarizability Measurements https://doi.org/10.1016/S0065-2199(08)60081-0 although this is about atomic beams; this is about molecular beams https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0144235X.2015.1077838 with an enormous bibliography